# Assign part of a command's output to a variable in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have this update script i am working on and i am using ssh to log onto the machine and simply run apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y. Now the thing is i want to be able to say something like "hostname" updated successfully.

Here's what i have written right now:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=(192.168.1.23 192.168.1.40 192.168.1.41 192.168.1.42 192.168.1.43)
#ssh-key=~/.ssh/id_ed25519


for i in "${ip[@]}"; do {
  ssh -t victor@$i "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "Update went successfully";
    else
      echo "$(tput smul)$(tput setaf 1)Update failed$(tput rmul)";
      exit 1;
    fi
} done;
```

with the same ssh -t command i was thinking if i could get the hostname and assign it to a variable at the same time i'm using the first ssh session. That is so i dont have to write in my password for the ssh key twice.

So something like this:

```
hostname=$"(ssh -t victor@$i hostname && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y"
```

And then i just echo $hostname.

Comment: BTW, instead of `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`, it's better just to put the `ssh` command into the `if` statement in-line: `if ssh -t "victor<$i" "..."; then`

Comment: BTW, another way to do this is with [SSH multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) to send multiple separate commands over one authenticated transport.

Comment: Quick note -- feel free to add your own answer if you're so inclined, but answers shouldn't be included into the question itself, as they "privilege" that answer, making it above community review (prohibiting community voting on the answer distinct from voting on the question).

Comment: Another thing is that right now, you're checking the exit status of the command `hostname=${hostname%$'\r'}`, not the exit status of the `ssh` command (and if you just removed the `hostname=` line without making any other changes, you'd be checking the exit status of `cat`). Please adopt the edits in the current version of my answer if you want to detect failed `apt-get` commands reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ read -r hostname; read -r -d '' rest; retval=$?; } < <(
  ssh "victor@$i" "
    hostname || echo
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && printf '\0'
  "
)
printf '%s\n' "$rest"
if [[ $retval = 0 ]]; then  ## this is intentionally a string comparison, not numeric
  echo "Remote SSH command was successful"
else
  echo "Remote SSH command failed"
fi
```

Let's break this down into pieces:

- `<(...)` is *process substitution* syntax, which substitutes a filename which will, when read from, return the output of a subshell running the given commands. Thus, `< <(...)` is redirecting from this process substitution.
- `read -r hostname`, run locally, reads a single line into the variable named `hostname`.
- `read -r -d '' rest` reads up to the next NUL character, with a successful exit status if such a NUL is seen, and an unsuccessful exit status if not.
- `hostname || echo` writes the system's hostname (if successful) or an empty line (otherwise).
- `... && printf '\0'` puts a NUL on the end of the output from `ssh` (causing `read -r -d '' rest` to exit with a successful exit status) *only if the commands in `...` succeeded*.

(Simplified from the original answer to no longer need bash 4.4 to detect when the remote apt-get commands failed).

Comment: Hey thanks! That's super appreciated with the break down!

However, it does not quite work, at least not the way i'm implementing it. I still cant echo $hostname since it's still empty. That is when the command completed successfully. I basically just replaced my "ssh -t victor@$i "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y" with the command you provided above.

Comment: The above **will** populate the local variable `hostname` if run exactly as I gave it.

Comment: ...now, if you had a command substitution surrounding, *that* would cause the captured value to be lost. Could you paste the exact code and a transcript of running it with `bash -x` on https://gist.github.com/? In an *ideal* world, `PS4=':$LINENO:$BASHPID+'` would be set (passed in on the environment in earlier versions of bash, or at the top of the file in 4.4), so we could verify that the `read hostname` and the place you `echo "$hostname"` are run in the same process..

Comment: (As an aside, I'd tend to suggest adjusting your remote `/etc/sudoers` to not require a TTY rather than using `ssh -t` -- less chance of `apt-get` engaging behavior that's only meant to be active in interactive use that way).

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/critaL/4a89f2cbcdecf42e10c05a2174794bab

This is what my script looks like now. And yeah, i will fix that in the future i just want to get this working first :)

Comment: Could you edit that gist to add the `bash -x` log, ideally with the `PS4` I provided above? (There's support for having multiple files in a single gist).

Comment: So, that log shows that we did indeed capture the hostname -- but that the value we captured has a carriage return on the end of it. So it was sending the cursor back to the beginning of the line when it was printed, so the next line would overwrite it.

Comment: `hostname=${hostname%$'\r'}` will remove a trailing carriage return, and is thus one way to fix that problem.

Comment: Or you could use `printf '%q\n' "$hostname"` to print it in such a way as to render the carriage return to a printable/visible escape sequence, instead of using `echo` (which is unreliable for a great many reasons, not just that one).

Comment: (as an aside, I wonder if your *literal* hostname has a carriage return -- which could happen if you'd used a Windows text editor to create your `/etc/hostname` or other config files, for example -- or if that's just an artifact of content being written for TTY use).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139602/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-nillenilsson).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
hostname="$(nmblookup -A <ip>)"
```

and then

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "$hostname: Update went successfully."
else
  echo "$hostname: Update failed!"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks but nmblookup does not work in this case, i get no reply from the hosts. I tried disabling the firewall but it did not work.

Comment: `nmblookup` is very specific to Windows-esque environments. If you want to do a more generic reverse DNS lookup, that's something more like `dig +short -x "$ip"` -- though it's still not guaranteed to be a match for what the host *thinks* its name is, as reported by `hostname`.